# dynamic html pages in php

Tags: php, apache

im new to php and im try to work on dynamic html pages with php
everything seemed to ok but when i try to make pages dynamically
an error shows up like this

```
Notice: Undefined index: page in C:\xampp\htdocs\myfolder\website\inter.php on line 5
```

i checked it out on the net and someone insisted on using this(@) in front of $ it worked 
though when i try to click on the navbar the design button i get this error

The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of that page about the error.

```
<?php

include ("includes/header.html");
include ("includes/navbar.html");
if ($_GET['page'] == "design") {
      include ("includes/design.html"); 
}
else {
     include ("includes/home.html");
}  

include ("includes/footer.html");
?>
```

somebody help because this error is pulling backwards

Comment: [`@`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) suppresses the error message. You really should not use it at all. There are very few cases in which you can't avoid to use it, but this is not one of them.

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid using `@` & check if the variable is set befor using e.g`isset()`

```
<?php

include ("includes/header.html");
include ("includes/navbar.html");
if (isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] == "design"){
      include ("includes/design.html"); 
  }else{
     include ("includes/home.html");
}  

include ("includes/footer.html");
?>
```

And for some extra credit look at the switch case statement as your script grows its much cleaner to use:

```
<?php
include ("includes/header.html");
include ("includes/navbar.html");

$page=(isset($_GET['page']))?$_GET['page']:'home';
switch($page){
    case "home":
        include ("includes/home.html");
        break;
    case "design":
        include ("includes/design.html");
        break;
    case "otherPage":
        include ("includes/otherpage.html");
        break;
    default:
        include ("includes/404.html");
        break;
}

include ("includes/footer.html");
?>
```

Comment: NEVER EVER just use `@` to suppress warnings which can just be handled! It's not like when you don't see it anymore the problem just goes away you know :)

Comment: @PeeHaa couldn't agree more, thou sometimes I use the suppressor within a view to hide unused vars instead of checking each and every one.

Answer (score 1):

The error message says that the index `page` in the array `$_GET` is **not** defined (i.e. no `?page=xxx`).

So what do you want to do when there's no page passed to the script?

You can check with `isset()` if a variable is set:

```
<?php

include ("includes/header.html");
include ("includes/navbar.html");

// $page defaults to an empty string
// If the "page" parameter isn't passed, this script will include "home.html"
$page = '';
if ( isset($_GET['page']) )
  $page = $_GET['page'];

if ($page == "design")
{
      include ("includes/design.html");
}

else // If $page isn't "design" (, "...") or $page is an empty string, include "home.html"!
{
     include ("includes/home.html");
}  

include ("includes/footer.html");
?>
```

By the way you shouldn't use the `@` which suppresses all warnings! There are many reasons ;)

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line:

```
if ($_GET['page'] == "design") {
```

with this one:

```
if (isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] == "design") {
```

This change let you to first check if the 'page' key exists in the $_GET array and then (if if it's true) check if the value is "design".

Don't use the @ in front of the statement. It's used to shut down error messages but this will make hard to debug you application.

Comment: thanks guys the first error has been handle but im still seeing this when i click on the design button on the navbar i see this error message,"The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of that page about the error"

Comment: @thequantumtheories Try to use the same criteria in the other pages, where you get the error.

Answer (score 0):

You, most probably, request your page at http://localhost/ or http://127.0.0.1/ using browser. 
$_GET is a global array in PHP which consists of variables passed to the PHP script using GET request method. 
Like this:

http://www.google.com/search?q=php

`search` is a script, `?q=php` is a GET request.
Just pass `?page=design` to your script and `page` variable will be available using $_GET array.
So you should type something like http://localhost/index.php?page=design in your browser address.